# Eliminar valores nulos ("nan") en un array

Tags: python, array, matrices, numpy

¿Cual sería la forma mas eficiente para reemplazar "Nan" por ceros en una gran matriz de datos numéricos en Python usando Numpy?

Comment: tu pregunta se basa en opiniones y no entra en el tipo de preguntas aceptadas por la comunidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente asigna el valor que quieras usando como máscara boleana la salida de [numpy.isnan](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html#numpy.isnan):

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> a = np.array([[1, np.NaN, 2],
                  [3, 4, np.NaN],
                  [np.NaN, 9, 8]])

>>> a
array([[  1.,  nan,   2.],
       [  3.,   4.,  nan],
       [ nan,   9.,   8.]])

>>> a[np.isnan(a)] = 0      #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>>> a
array([[ 1.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  9.,  8.]])
```

---

En el supuesto que tus datos vengan de una lista o cualquier estructura en la que los valores NaN sean en realidad cadenas de texto ("NaN", "Nan", "nan", etc), puedes usar el argumento `dtype` a la hora de construir el array para definir el tipo de forma explícita:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> l = [[1, "Nan", 2],
         [3, 4, "Nan"],
         ["Nan", 9, 8]]
>>> a = np.array(l, dtype = np.float)
>>> a[np.isnan(a)] = 0
```